# png not being rendered properly in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm new to SDL & I'm trying to render a simple image & this is my code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include<SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;    
    SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", 100, 50, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Surface* optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(IMG_Load("glow.png"), gScreenSurface->format, 0);

    SDL_BlitSurface(optimizedSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_Delay(5000);    
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

but when I run it, I'm getting this type of output
[image]

and here's how the [image](https://freepngimg.com/thumb/light/2-2-light-free-download-png.png) really looks like

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is the image background white or transparent?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's transparent, you can download the image and see for yourself

Comment: Then `gScreenSurface->format` probably has no alpha-channel.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat makes sense but what direction should I look in to solve it? this is like my hello world program so I'm clueless

Comment: Normally you don't need to use surfaces at all. Instead you do `SDL_CreateRenderer` after creating the window, use `IMG_LoadTexture` to load the image as a texture, and draw it with `SDL_RenderCopy`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks! I'll look into that (u can submit an answer if you want) and if you don't mind answering a little side question,  in the line `SDL_Surface* optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(IMG_Load("glow.png"), gScreenSurface->format, 0);` I directly used `IMG_Load()` so will that produce any garbage memory since I'm not using `SDL_FreeSurface`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by garbage memory, but yes, you have a memory leak.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yea sorry i meant memory leaks, any clue on how to fix it?

Comment: Create a separate variable, initialize it with `IMG_Load("glow.png")`. Pass the variable to `SDL_ConvertSurface`. Then dispose of it using `SDL_FreeSurface`.